# Vite: env variable used with equality operators in ternary always evaluates to false

Tags: vite

Due to quirks with the CI/CD on my project, I can not use NODE_ENV or mode, so I need to introduce one more variable:
so my vite config has `envPrefix: MY_PROJECT,`

`config.js:`

```
export const ENVIRONMENT = MY_PROJECT_ENVIRONMENT;
```

When I run the following code:

```
import { ENVIRONMENT } from 'config.js';

console.log({
    env: ENVIRONMENT,
    isProd: ENVIRONMENT === 'prod',
    isStage: ENVIRONMENT === 'stage',
    echoForStage:
      ENVIRONMENT === 'stage'
        ? 'shown'
        : 'NOT shown',
    echoForProd:
      ENVIRONMENT === 'prod'
        ? 'shown'
        : 'NOT shown',
});
```

The results are:

| ENVIRONMENT | stage | prod |
| --- | --- | --- |
| env | stage | prod |
| isProd | `false` | `true` |
| isStage | `true` | `false` |
| echoForStage | NOT shown | NOT Shown |
| echoForProd | NOT shown' | NOT Shown |

Not sure if this is intended behavior where for some value `env`, `ENVIRONMENT === env` returns `true`, but when used in ternary, it will always evaluates to `false`.

Comment: You should check the compiled code and see what's executed in reality